# Simple app doesn't bind to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I wrote a simple first app in AngularJS starting from a template for a todo list. None of the functions defined binds the scope (Both adding a new task or edit the current once). Anything I am doing commonly wrong in all the scopes of the controller?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="page-container">

     <h2>Todo</h2>

     <ul class="todo-list" ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index">
        <li>
          <span>{{ todo }}</span>
          <button class="bt bt-achieve" ng-click="done(todo)">Done</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <ul class="add-todo">
        <li>
          <input type="text" class="txt" placeholder="New Todo" ng-model="newTodo" ng-keyup="add($event)" />
        </li>
    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

And my JS Script:

```
var app = angular.module('Todo', []);

app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.newTodo = '';

  $scope.todos = [
    'Maged Task', 
    'Essam Task',
    'Ashraf Task'
  ];

  $scope.done = function(todo) {
    var indexOf = $scope.todos.indexOf(todo);
    if (indexOf !== -1) {
      $scope.todos.splice(indexOf, 1);
    }
  };

   $scope.add = function(e) {
    if (e.which && e.which === 13) {
      $scope.todos.push($scope.newTodo);
      $scope.newTodo = '';
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Also see Mike West's article [Scope in JavaScript](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/).

Comment: Guys I will have to get take one answer even if all you were correct. I will go with who's first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `<body>` to `<body ng-app="Todo" ng-controller=TodoCtrl>`

Comment: Thanks, now it adds the new todo, but can't edit the listed once, even if editing button of listed works, but the element is not editable.

Answer (score 1):

you haven't bound to the angular app or controller.

Try

`<body ng-app="ToDo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">`

Comment: Thanks, now it adds the new todo, but can't edit the listed once, even if editing button of listed works, but the element is not editable.

Answer (score 1):

Change the body tag as below

```
<body ng-app="Todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl" >
```

I always prefer to give initial data in ng-init method .

In your code you can use the initial data for $scope.todos like as below.

**html code :**

```
<body ng-app="Todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl" ng-init="initialData()" >
```

**javascript code**

**Inside controller**

```
 $scope.initialData = function(){

  $scope.newTodo = '';

  $scope.todos = [
    'Maged Task', 
    'Essam Task',
    'Ashraf Task'
  ];

}
```

Comment: Please let me show the code exactly what you have done .Please give js fiddle link  then i can easly understand the problem .

Comment: take a look  :        var app = angular.module('Todo', []);
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.initialData = function () {
    $scope.newTodo = '';

   $scope.todos = [
    'Maged Task', 
    'Essam Task',
    'Ashraf Task'
   ]; 
  }
  $scope.done = function(todo) {
    var indexOf = $scope.todos.indexOf(todo);
    if (indexOf !== -1) {
      $scope.todos.splice(indexOf, 1);
    }
  };

   $scope.add = function(e) {
    if (e.which && e.which === 13) {
      $scope.todos.push($scope.newTodo);
      $scope.newTodo = '';
    }
  };
});

Comment: Hi , I saw your jsfiddle link .                                                                           I saw the fallowing problem with my broswer debugger .                      Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://fiddle.jshell.net/9bdkhy2m/show/css/style.css                               Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://fiddle.jshell.net/9bdkhy2m/show/js/script.js                                Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: But i am not sure these are the actual problem  what you have .  Please take a look at . these problems in jsfiddle . I think jsfiddle unable to load script.js file . Please take a look at this .

Comment: Hi , I got the answer . It is just an integration problem in the js fiddle . I was just moved all script code to an script tag then it was working fine .

Comment: Yes it works fine for me as well. The elements are not suppose to be editable, I got confused! Thanks